# Qt combobox: Event when item is selected

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, cc

i need to know what is the way to run a function when one item of the combobox is selected/clicked, i tried with the standar connect:

```
connect(ui->combobox,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(clickedaction()));
```

... but it doesnt work.

I dont even need a custom action per element, just the same for all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "doesnt work" means what? just nothing happens, or is there an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no signal *clicked()* in *QComboBox*.

If you need to detect the item activation either by mouse click or enter pressed then use activated(int index).

```
connect(ui->combobox,SIGNAL(activated(int)),this,SLOT(clickedaction(int)));
```